# Port forwarding with iptables prerouting not work

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, nat, port, port-forwarding

I have 3 server

- server A: 5.161.x.x
- server B: 193.151.x.x
- server C: 195.96.x.x

I want to forward all traffic from server B and C to server A
,i forwarded Server B to server A with this command:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 442:65533 -j DNAT --to-destination 5.161.x.x
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

its work but when i want forward traffic from server C to A with same command its not work.

The point is that **it works to any address I forward to, but it doesn't work when I forward to server A**

- i dont need port 1-442. just need 442-65533
- in server A port 443 have page and i test with this page

[iptables -t nat -v -L PREROUTING -n --line-number image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqxe9.png)

Comment: Please clarify how are server B and C different. Are they both connected to server A directly?

Comment: There is no difference between these two servers. Both of them use ubuntu. (only the data centers are different).Yes, they are connected (I checked again with the `ping` command)

Comment: Can you post a tcpdump from both showing the traffic?

Comment: how to tcpdump? `sudo tcpdump -D`?